# Session replication on EAP JBOSS 6.0

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

I am working on Struts 2 framework with EAP Jboss 6. My project session variables were stored and retrieved using 'HTTP Session Map'. When I moved on to the Domain mode of Jboss with Clustering my session values were lost while switching between different nodes of the server. Then I configured Sticky session and stored the session values in Cookies. Even though I could able to retrieve value from cookie on the first request, the HTTP session was lost.  Currently I'm using Apache Mod Cluster for clustering the configuration is as follows.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so

LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

Listen 192.168.5.30:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.30:80>
 ManagerBalancerName my-cluster
 ServerName NSN
<Directory />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Location /mod_cluster-manager>
    SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
EnableMCPMReceive
#ProxyPass / balancer://my-cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
 ProxyPass / balancer://my-cluster stickysession=off nofailover=On
 ProxyPassReverse / balancer://my-cluster
 ProxyPreserveHost On

      KeepAliveTimeout 60

      ServerAdvertise On
```

Now searched and found something about  mod_cluster(https://github.com/modcluster/mod_cluster). In that it is mentioned to put the folder to 'deploy directory of a JBoss server profile'. But in EAP Jboss 6.0 domain mode I don't know where is deploy directory and how to configure that mod cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved session replication by configuring jboss-web.xml under WEB-INF folder as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="6.0"
       xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd">
<replication-config>
    <!-- The default value is SET_AND_NON_PRIMITIVE_GET, therefore the byte array which is carrying the data is considered
non-primitive and would cause replication even in read only scenario. -->
    <replication-trigger>SET</replication-trigger>

    <!-- Replicating entire session is the default. -->
    <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
   <replication-mode>SYNCHRONOUS</replication-mode>
</replication-config>
```

In this case no need to use cookies to store values...